# QML Image scale unexpected behavior

Tags: qml

Qt 5.9.2

The following QML code:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 585
    height: 113
    title: qsTr("test")
    Rectangle
    {
        width: 585
        height: 113
        color: "black"
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }
    Image
    {
        source: "balloon.png"
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }
}
```

produces the expected result:

[image]

When I add `scale: 0.5` to `Image` element, I get this:

[image]

But I expected it to look like this:

[image]

Can somebody please explain me why 0.5 scaled image is not located at (0,0) coordinates as it explicitly set in its properties and can something be done here for the scaled image to be located at (0,0) coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation for `scale`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#scale-prop), scaling is applied from the [`transformOrigin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transformOrigin-prop), and the default origin is `Item.Center`, so you need to specify `Item.TopLeft`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 585
    height: 113
    title: qsTr("test")

    Rectangle {
        width: 585
        height: 113
        color: "black"
        x: 0
        y: 0
    }
    Image {
        source: "balloon.png"
        x: 0
        y: 0
        scale: 0.5
        transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
    }
}
```

The `x` and `y` properties only affect an item's position, not its scaling origins. Note that there's also the [`transform`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transform-prop) property if you need to do more advanced transformations.

Comment: Be careful also, when anchoring to scaled `Item`s, as it does not scale the bounding box.